# How can I store data between web pages?

Tags: javascript, session, web-applications, session-state

How can I store some information between pages with JS ?

My webapp is using sql queries to populate a couple pages and those queries usually return the same result. Is there a way to store this result in a JS variable, and force a refresh with sql queries only at some events ?

And how efficient is this vs. SQL queries ? vs. a cookie ?

Comment: What's the question? What is better or how to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try [Local Storage.](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

```
function supportsLocalStorage() {
  try {
    return 'localStorage' in window && window['localStorage'] !== null;
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}

function saveGameState() {
    if (!supportsLocalStorage()) { return false; }
    localStorage["halma.game.in.progress"] = gGameInProgress;
    for (var i = 0; i < kNumPieces; i++) {
    localStorage["halma.piece." + i + ".row"] = gPieces[i].row;
    localStorage["halma.piece." + i + ".column"] = gPieces[i].column;
    }
    localStorage["halma.selectedpiece"] = gSelectedPieceIndex;
    localStorage["halma.selectedpiecehasmoved"] = gSelectedPieceHasMoved;
    localStorage["halma.movecount"] = gMoveCount;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also follow the [single page web app](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) pattern and use Ajax, look up [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) for more info

If you go further, you can lookup frameworks such as [Meteor](http://meteor.com/) that can be setup to push updates to the client only if there are changes (there are other ways, but I like how meteor does it)